# Using Scrapy and xpath to extract text

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to use xpath to extract text from the following html:

```
<p class="event-meta" xpath="1">Nanizanka / <span itemprop="genre">Akcija</span>,

                        <span itemprop="partOfSeason" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWorkSeason">
                        <span itemprop="seasonNumber">8</span>. sezona,
                        </span>

                        <span itemprop="episodeNumber">9</span>. del,

                United states of America


                    <br><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <span>
                        51
                    </span> min |
                    IMDB: 7,3 |

                        <span>★</span>
                        <span>★</span>
                        <span>★</span>
                        <span>★</span>
                        <span>★</span>
                        <span>★</span>
                        <span>★</span>
                        <span class="hollow-star">★</span>
                        <span class="hollow-star">★</span>
                        <span class="hollow-star">★</span>


                </p>
```

I'm having a problem extracting United States of America and IMDB score, since they don't have any tags?
I can't get beyond

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='row nogutter article']/div[@class='col-10']/main/article/p[@class='event-meta']//text()").extract()
```

since I need just the country and IMDB score as two separate items.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try `//span[@itemprop="episodeNumber"]/following-sibling::text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
score = response.xpath('//text()[contains(., "IMDB:")]').re_first(r'IMDB:\s*(\S+)')
country = response.xpath('//span[@itemprop][last()]/following-sibling::text()').get()
```